# How to retrieve the visible part of a SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a layout where the top part is used to display some data (eg. simple UI widgets) and the bottom part has a `SurfaceView` where I display a `CameraPreview`.

In order for this `SurfaceView` to extend the whole width of the screen and at the same time maintain a correct aspect ratio, the `SurfaceView` actually goes offscreen which is fine since I actually want the app to be divided evenly between the top part and the bottom part.

The problem is that I now want to retrieve only the visible part of the `SurfaceView` (ideally as a bitmap) but if I try to do it by setting a `PictureCallBack`, the aspect ratios of the picture data returned are just not quite the same as the ones shown in the SurfaceView (I've tried with all of the available `getSupportedPictureSizes`).

Any ideas how to tackle this problem? I've attached an image which better illustrates this problem.
[image]

Comment: have u got the solution. I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

it contains a barcode scanner project in that they have used a rectangle and capture particular area from the surfaceview it will be useful for u .. Hope so they use viewFinderView class to capture the area from the surface

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it but it was overly complicated. What I ended up doing was actually working directly with Camera.PreviewCallback and crop the correct image size I needed from the byte[] data provided by this method and not Camera.PictureCallback.

Comment: If anyone else is trying to solve a similar issue, let me know and I'll post the code here.

Comment: Can you please share your code here. Working on the same issue.